# Lens K8s unable to connect to terminal in Window's 10

Tags: windows, kubernetes, terminal, windows-subsystem-for-linux

There is no terminal coming in the Lens. Lens terminal just showing **connecting...**

Answer (score 2):

**Root Cause**

Bydefault lens uses the powershell but Lens need wsl shell. By changing the shell to wsl this issue can be solve also we have to add the path for wsl in lens application.

In the backend Lens call the **WSL** shell. But Lens unable to find it.

**Solution**

We can solve this issue by setting up the system environment variables.

1. Go to the Preferences and set **Terminal** as **wsl.exe**.
2. Set environment for **wsl.exe**. Go to System Variable and add the PATH.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Had this error on my Windows 10, Lens: 2023.10.122002-latest.

Had to change my Terminal Shell Path to `powershell.exe`. It was configured to use Google Cloud SDK Shell.

Answer (score 0):

Another Alternative to solve this:

[image]